# MarkLogic - mlcp job not returning success message to scheduler

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9, marklogic-dhf

We are using mlcp version 9.0.6.
Platform : Linux

When ever we run mlcp job through our enterprise scheduler Zena, the task is failing on Zena though mlcp is completed successfully.

We tried running gradle harmonize job through the same task and it ran successfully. We also tried a simple file move functionality and that is also successful. But mlcp is not returning the expected success response back to our enterprise scheduler, causing our enterprise scheduler task to fail.

Below is a sample log returned by mlcp. As the log indicates, mlcp load is successful and I am able to verify the data in STAGING DB, however, mlcp is not communicating the success response back to scheduler.

Error: 19/05/09 15:47:48 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner: Content type: XML
19/05/09 15:47:48 INFO contentpump.ContentPump: Job name: local_1527018875_1
19/05/09 15:47:48 INFO contentpump.FileAndDirectoryInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
19/05/09 15:47:50 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner:  completed 47%
19/05/09 15:47:51 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner:  completed 100%
19/05/09 15:48:23 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner: com.marklogic.mapreduce.MarkLogicCounter: 
19/05/09 15:48:23 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner: INPUT_RECORDS: 2798
19/05/09 15:48:23 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner: OUTPUT_RECORDS: 2798
19/05/09 15:48:23 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner: OUTPUT_RECORDS_COMMITTED: 2798
19/05/09 15:48:23 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner: OUTPUT_RECORDS_FAILED: 0
19/05/09 15:48:23 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner: Total execution time: 35 sec

### Update

Here is the mlcp code

```
#!/bin/bash

mlcp.sh import -ssl \
-host testhost \
-port 8010 \
-username unm \
-password pw \
-mode local \
-input_file_path /data/SourceFiles/QA/Customer \
-input_file_type aggregates \
-aggregate_record_namespace "http://new.webservice.namespace" \
-output_collections customerstaging,customerHarmonize \
-output_permissions data-hub-role,read,data-hub-role,update \
-output_uri_prefix /customer/ \
-aggregate_record_element PartyDownload \
-thread_count 48 \
-transform_module /ext/reusefunctions/customerDocument.sjs

exit 0
```

It has an explicit 'exit 0' at the end, but still the job failing. We are able to successfully run harmonize step as below.

```
(cd /data/EODH && gradle hubRunFlow -PentityName="customer" PflowName="customer-harmonize-process" -PflowType="harmonize" -PenvironmentName=uat -PthreadCount=32)

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "Success: Files moved."
  exit 0
else
  echo "Failure."
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Can you provide specific details on how you invoke MLCP from within the scheduler, and can you tell which version of MLCP you are using?

Comment: Also, how does the scheduler detect success or failure.  Is it purely by return code or is it parsing the output of the task? Have you looked at https://support.asg.com/OP/ZNH/znzug/usingzenautilities/zena_exit_code.htm

Comment: We are using mlcp version 9.0.6. on Linux Platform. Zena looks for a return code of zero to be marked as successful.